# Select everything, based on distinct USER ID in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select * from an oracle table, but only where user_id are unique.

i tried this:

```
select distinct user_id from users; -- which worked
```

i want to display EVERYTHING, so when i put:

```
select distinct user_id, * from users; -- i get a syntax error
```

how can i accomplish his?

Comment: Erm, your query makes no sense. If there's multiple rows for a given user_id ... what would you expect to be returned?

Comment: i don't care which it returns, i just want one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct user_id, users.* from users;
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users`?

Comment: thank you, i found the problem, it was in a stupid space after one of the user_ids. it was treating them as unique in Oracle, but not in Sql Sever. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from users where users.primary_key IN 
  (select primary_key FROM users GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

This will only select records that do not share user_ids with other rows.